# Match digits in regex statement

Tags: .net, regex

My goal is to capture the last page of the report and I want to achieve it by matching the header that describes the page numbers. 
My last page of the report contains the following string that I want to match (it could be also a two digit or four digit number as well):

> Page: 877 of 877

The regex that I tried to use is

```
Page:\s (\d+) of \1
```

but this captures the following case as well:

> Page: 8 of 877

I understand the regex expressions are read left to right but is there a way to capture the second number, 877, and then match it with the first number? (some kind of back refernece)
I use regex engine of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the end-of-string character `$` to the end of your regex, it would only match `\1` at the end of your string.  That would only match on the last page.

https://regex101.com/r/W05R9g/1

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I don't suggest...

`^Page:\s*(\d{1})\s*of\s*\1$|^Page:\s*(\d{2})\s*of\s*\2$|^Page:\s*(\d{3})\s*of\s*\3$`

Then extend this to your max digits (this one is 3)

I do suggest using regex to get two capture groups (first number) and (last number) and then using whatever language you're using to compare them instead of getting regex to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is something that would work for me as well. Thank you +1